# How to enable laptop integrated webcam in vmware using ubuntu 14.04 (as Guest), WIN 7 (as HOST)

Tags: windows-7, laptop, webcam, ubuntu-14.04, vmware-player

i'm using Ubuntu 14.04 under vmware and i want to activate the integrated webcam , i'm using windows 7 64bits and the camera is working properly in The HOST

Using cheese it give : `No device found`
I have also tried `sudo modprobe uvcvideo`

But it seems that the camera won't be activated
using : `sudo modprobe uvcvideo`

```
Module                  Size  Used by
uvcvideo               81073  0 
videobuf2_vmalloc      13216  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_memops       13362  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_core         59104  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_common            15681  1 videobuf2_core
videodev              153793  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
media                  21903  2 uvcvideo,videodev
```

the camera is a TOSHIBA web camera

Any help ?, thanks

Comment: I'm working the other way round (WinXP in VMware VM on Ubuntu 15.04 host) and the camera works fine in the VM. The laptop camera appears in the hardware device list in the bottom right of the VM window (you can't see it in full screen). I need to click on it to enable it, but after doing so XP graphics applications see it as an import source.

Comment: I've also tried a 64-bit Ubuntu 14.04 VM (same host as before) and the camera works with `cheese` once I attach it to the VM. If you cannot see the camera on the status bar you should be able to find it in the **Virtual Machines** menu -> **Removable Devices**.

Comment: @AFH For me there is no hardware device list in the bottom right of the VM window  and also cheese give me error and there is no camera in Virtual Machines menu -> Removable Devices

Comment: some laptop webcams run on the usb bus. Can you attach it to the vm as a usb device ? that might work better.

Comment: @kent i have already said in the title that i"m using integrated webcam .. it on the screen and it's a toshiba web camera

Comment: @Frankenstein My HP laptop has a similar "integrated" camera, but it still a USB device and to use it on a guest OS it has to be a USB device mapped to the VM. "Integrated" is just like your TouchPad or keypad, they are still USB peripherals, just because it doesn't have a visible plug-in doesn't mean it uses some proprietary method to communicate with the rest of the hardware.

Comment: @Frankenstein most integrated camera on modern laptops are acually on the usb bus. just because you cant unplug it does not change that fact.

Comment: @acejavelin thanks but what do you mean by it need to be mapped ? that what i want to do

Comment: @kent thanks i didn't know that but i still want a source for that :) but how can i attach it to the VM as a usb device ? i don't if the issue comes from the VM or from the Ubuntu itself !!!

Comment: @Frankenstein I am not intimately familiar with VMware, but it should be something similar to VirtualBox where you can virtually "connect" USB peripherals to a VM. If you Google "vmware x.x connect usb device" with your specific VMware version, the first result (for the ones I tested) took me directly to VMware's documenation on their website with exactly how to do it.

Comment: @acejavelin ok good i'll try and let you know